# Wrong data shows while running the batch file in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-prompt, windows

I am facing an issue to run the command batch file through C#. Actually I have created a batch File named **Log.bat** which is used to get file size of all directory files. I put this batch file in my desktop. when I run this it successfully retrieve the directories and their files size.

My script of batch file is:

```
dir /s > "C:\Documents and Settings\dinesh.kumar\Desktop\LogFile.txt"
```

This given path is my file saved location.
Output:

```
Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\dinesh.kumar\Desktop\Color Cop

10/24/2007  12:08 AM            97,792 ColorCop.exe
08/10/2006  03:12 PM            26,235 ColorCop.HLP
08/10/2006  03:12 PM               372 file_id.diz
10/23/2007  11:50 PM             1,332 license.txt
10/24/2007  12:06 AM            10,877 readme.txt
           5 File(s)        136,608 bytes
```

Now I have developed an windows application to run that batch file in c#.
my code for run the batch file is:

```
protected void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Documents and Settings\\dinesh.kumar\\Desktop\\Log.bat");
}
```

But when I run this application, it creates the LogFile.txt on desktop but it give the files of microsoftvisualstudio directory like this.
Output

```
Directory of C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE

08/11/2011  12:53 PM    <DIR>          .
08/11/2011  12:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/29/2011  04:14 PM    <DIR>          1033
09/23/2005  02:53 AM            27,648 cmddef.dll
09/23/2005  04:24 AM           257,024 compluslm.dll
09/23/2005  03:37 AM           139,264 csformatui.dll
09/23/2005  07:15 AM            33,792 custsat.dll
09/23/2005  07:15 AM         1,038,848 dbghelp.dll
09/22/2005  11:16 PM            27,112 dteproperties.tlb
06/29/2011  04:14 PM    <DIR>          ExceptionAssistantContent
06/29/2011  04:14 PM    <DIR>          HTML
08/11/2011  12:53 PM            96,032 LogFile.txt
09/23/2005  06:56 AM            19,456 MakeZipExe.exe
09/23/2005  06:56 AM           393,216 Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll
09/23/2005  06:56 AM             6,144 Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll
```

Sorry the data is so long. I cant paste in it.

Why is it not shows desktop directories and their files.
What did I do wrong? Any code or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What directory is your WinForms running in?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a batch file for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your working directory is set to the application's directory when you call Process.Start.

Use the overload of Process.Start which accepts a ProccessStartInfo, then set the WorkingDirectory to the path of the batch file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your process code which your launch to take the directory which you want (may be hardcode da path) and not the working dir as TJ said.

Comment: There are few, if any, good reasons to hardcode something like a path in a program, IMO.

Comment: Its best practice to make it a variable, or a constant, instead of using the text of the path each time.

Comment: @Tim, yea, hence i said "May be" :)